# How to mysql config in django setting

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I tried to connect MySQL in Django. but it's throwing an error on **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'yourdbname'")** how to solve this error .

**Setting**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'yourdbname',                              
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                 
    'PORT': '3306',                      
},
}
```

I tried to different ways to solve this issue. but it's not working This is first time I am working on muysql to connect django.

Comment: where is db user mentioned in code?

Comment: No, I will not mention any DB user in my code

Comment: Which version of mysql?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you don't want to mention **username** **password** in your settings file.

In that case, try something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

Where the `my.cnf` is

```
[client]
database = db_name
user = db_user
password = db_password
default-character-set = utf8
```

Also, since this is your first time setting up MYSQL + Django, here is a guide which I'm sure should be helpful:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database